# jquery search autosuggest very slow

Tags: jquery

I have autosuggest search field, but the results are loading so very slow, I think it may be my mistake. Please take a look at the code and suggest me :)

I have database table with around 1000 results (thus not much).
maybe should stop searches on entering new charcter, or sth ...
thank in advance for suggestions.

```
<div class="searching">
<form id="search" name="searchForm" class="sform" action="index" method="post" autocomplete="off">
    <input type="text" name="keywords" id="inputString"  class="searches"  />
    <input type="submit" name="submit_btn" class="button"  />
</form>

<div class="results">
    <div class="inner">
        <?php //print_r($_POST);
        if(isset($_POST['results']) && !empty($_POST['results'])){
            ?>
            <ul>
            <?php
            foreach($_POST['results'] as $row){
                echo $_POST['results'];
            }
            ?>
            </ul>
            <?php
        }
        ?>
    </div>
</div>
</div>
//tried to use suggestion I found here - with set timeout
$("#inputString").keyup(function(e){
    clearTimeout($.data(this, 'timer'));
    if (e.keyCode == 13)
      search(true);
    else
      $(this).data('timer', setTimeout(search, 100));
    e.preventDefault();
});      

function search(force) {
    var existingString = $("#inputString").val();
    if (!force && existingString.length < 1) return; 
    $('.res_items').slideDown('normal');
        dataString = $("#search").serialize();
        $.ajax({
            type:"POST",
            data:dataString,
            url: searchsuggest.php',

            success:function(data){

                if(data.success == 'yes'){
                    $('.res_items').show().load(' .inner_slide', {results:data.items});
                }
            },
            error: console.log('error')
        });
}

and then in ajax part I have a query with LIKE - which gives slower results

SELECT id, items FROM games WHERE itmes LIKE '".trim($_POST['keywords'])."%'" 
and output json data: 
$arr = array('success' => "yes", 'items' => $find_items);
header('Content-type: application/json');    
echo json_encode($arr);
```

Comment: Try limiting your sql query to top 50/100 records

Comment: using caching in the server

Comment: its not auto suggest search makes your data slow but it is because of your query rajesh is right you can make your result upto 50 or 100

Comment: @RajeshDhiman not sure if this will be ok with the client :( I mean - I suggested also to start a search only after 3 chars would be entered, or having queries that would start search at the beginning of the word

Comment: displaying 1000 results might not look good on screen and it also doesn't make sense to me or any other web user. I mean how could we find what we need from 1000 of records.

Comment: I know all that :) just not sure how to convince the client

Comment: Are you sure it is the javascript that is slow and it is not the PHP? You can check the respone time by using Firebug.

Comment: you can tell him that transfer of this huge data on every key press would result in slower results, and there is nothing much to do in javascript or server side code to optimize this issue.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is nothing much to do in your jQuery or php code. I think one possible solution is to limit your sql query to **top 50/100** results. I think that might be enough to be displayed as suggestions.

Transferring a huge amount of data per request would defiantly take a lot of time *( that is why paging is recommended on data grids)* and then writing that data to your html page will also consume some time.
You can also try indexing on your sql tables *(if it is not already there)*.